# alguien que me oriente con algo de for y foreach en c#

Tags: c#, bucle-for, foreach, color

El ejercicio me pide ingresar 2 números a través de un usuario, y determinar si están en el `array`. Si están, imprimir el mensaje "Bingo". Si no, un error que diga "no tuviste suerte" y "volver a intentar" dos veces más. No sé cómo seguir después de esto que planteo acá.

```
Console.WriteLine("============================================================================");
                Console.WriteLine("Bienvevenido a la grilla.");
                Console.WriteLine("============================================================================");
                Console.WriteLine("¿Desea participar? Es un juego al azar.");
                Console.WriteLine("1-Si ");
                Console.WriteLine("2-No ");
                Console.Write("Elija la opcion que desea: ");
                Num = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out opcion);
                if(Num && opcion==1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("============================================================================");
                    Console.WriteLine("Proceda a ingresar sus dos numeros.");
                    Console.WriteLine("============================================================================");
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Gracias de todos modos! Adios.");

                
                do{
                Console.WriteLine("Ingrese primer numero de la grilla (del 1 al 10 inclusive): ");
                Num = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out primer_numero);
                if(Num && primer_numero<=10)
                    Valor_primer_numero = primer_numero;
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("No es un numero valido.");
                }while(!Num || primer_numero>=11);

                do{
                Console.WriteLine("Ingrese segundo numero de la grilla: ");
                Num = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out segundo_numero);
                if(Num && segundo_numero != primer_numero && segundo_numero<=11)
                {    
                    Valor_segundo_numero = segundo_numero;
                    if(segundo_numero == primer_numero)
                    {
                    Console.WriteLine("=========================================================================");
                    Console.WriteLine("No puede ser igual al primer numero.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Presione una tecla e ingrese otro numero del 1 al 10.");
                    Console.WriteLine("=========================================================================");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    }
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("No es un numero valido.");
            }while(!Num || segundo_numero == primer_numero || segundo_numero>=11);

            for(int x=0;x<numeros.GetLength(0);x++)
                {
                    for(int y=0;y<numeros.GetLength(1);y++)
                    {                   
                        numeros[x,y] = rnd.Next(1,11);
                        Console.Write(numeros[x,y] + "\t");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(" ");
                    
                }
```

hasta acá me imprime la grilla, pero no le encuentro la solución a la parte de buscar si están dentro del array, e imprimir el los mensajes que necesito.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! si te imprime la grilla.. quiere decir que la saber recorrer.. entonces si la sabes recorrer.. podes comparar cada valor, con el que ingreso el usuario no?

Comment: es la primera vez que escribo por aca, ire mejorando. Si pero no se como comparar cada valor con el del usuario. Realizo el recorrido me imprime la grilla, y ya no se como comparar el ingreso del usuario con todos los numeros para ver si estan ahi. Gracias estoy tratando de hacerlo pero ya se me esta haciendo un lio.

Comment: yo veo que comparas valores en varios lados.. y sabes como recorrer la matriz... si podes recorrerla quiere decir que vas uno por uno, no? y si vas uno por uno, ahi podes comparar no?

Comment: Yo lo que comparo son condiciones de ingreso para cumplir unas consignas del ejercicio. Cuando recorro el for me trae la grilla con los numero aleatorios. Y de ahi quiero saber si los valores ingresados por el usuario estan en la grilla. ese es el problema que tengo. No estaria sabiendo como comparar los valores ingresados con el array.

Comment: Y si haces una iteracion exactamente igual a la que imprime la matriz por pantalla, y adentro agregas un if, que te diga si los valores son iguales a los que buscas, no te sirve?ç

Comment: Decis que realice un for despues de este para corroborar? Ya lo hice pero debo tomar mal los valores porque no me imprime lo que yo quiero. No se como decirle si estos dos numeros estan o no. Se que es un if, pero no se si agarro numeros[x,y] y los comparo con primer_numero y segundo_numero

Answer (score 1):

Primero deberías tener el array de números.

```
int[] numeros = new int[10];
for(i =0; i< numeros.length; i++)
{
   numeros[i] = rnd.Next(1,11);
}
```

Despés puedes comprobar si los números intorducidos por el usuario están en el array.

```
boolean primerNumer = false;
boolean segundoNumero = false;
for(i =0; i< numeros.length; i++)
{
   if (numero1 == numeros[i])
   {
     primerNumer = true;
   }
   if (numero2 == numeros[i])
   {
     segundoNumero = true;
   }
}
```